# Installing python-dev|python-devel for CentOS 7 (installing matplotlib error)

Tags: python, matplotlib, centos

Trying to install matplotlib on CentOS 7. When typing `sudo pip3 install matplotlib` I get the following error:

> SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install
>   python-dev|python-devel.

Does anyone know how to install the right packages? I tried `sudo pip3 install python-dev` and `sudo pip3 install python-devel` and they gave me the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dev
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for python-dev`

So I'm lost. Does anyone know what I could do to try and alleviate this error?

Comment: Try the systems package manager: `yum`, `rpm`...

Comment: @KlausD. Do you know the yum package name for matplotlib for Python 3+ ? I can only find the Python 2. And I've never tried or heard of rpm..

Comment: The error means try `yum install python-devel`, not `pip install python-devel`; then reinstall  Matplotlib using `pip`.